# MSBuild - Build Error because of dll Fakes

Tags: microsoft-fakes

Configuration :
Visual Studio 2012 Premium + Update 2

Hi, 
My unitTest project uses two Fake assemblies.
One of theses assemblies produces a build error and I really don't know why.
If I take off this assembly, the compilation is OK.
The error is "result: unexpected exception occured (-1002 - 0xfffffc16)"

I have seen some other post with the same error but it is because of Moles assembly.
Someone has a solution to fix this issue ?

Here is one part of the build result :

```
.fakes Fakes\Technical.Sdk.fakes will generate ...\Workflow.UnitTests\FakesAssemblies\Technical.Sdk.Fakes.dll
  verbosity: Warning
  x86: False
  framework version: v4.5
  target runtime version: v4.0.30319
  ReferenceFiles: 78
    ...\packages\AutoMapper.3.0.0-ci1037\lib\net40\AutoMapper.dll
    ...\packages\AutoMapper.3.0.0-ci1037\lib\net40\AutoMapper.Net4.dll
    ...\Lib\Directory.Proxy.dll
    ...\Lib\Platform.Common.dll
    ...\Lib\Platform.Interfaces.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Technical.EntityFramework.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Technical.Sdk.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Technical.ServiceBus.dll
    D:\371\BuildType\..\src\Main\Source\bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll
    ...\Lib\Microsoft\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
    ...\Lib\Moq\Moq.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
    ...\Lib\AutoFixture\Ploeh.AutoFixture.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll
    ...\bin\Release\WFCommon.Context.dll
    ...\bin\Release\WFCommon.DataTransferObjects.dll
    ...\bin\Release\WFCommon.LoggingExceptions.dll
    ...\bin\Release\WFCommon.ServiceBusContract.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Workflow.Bll.dll
    ...\Workflow.UnitTests\FakesAssemblies\Workflow.Bll.Fakes.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Workflow.BusinessObjects.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Workflow.Dal.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Workflow.ServerContext.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Workflow.ServiceBus.dll
    ...\bin\Release\EntityFramework.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Configuration.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.Entity.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Sdk.dll
    ...\bin\Release\PresentationCore.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\WindowsBase.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Sdk.Media.dll
    ...\bin\Release\RestSharp.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.Core.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.dll
    ...\bin\Release\...Technical.Util.dll
    ...\bin\Release\PresentationFramework.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.Composite.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Drawing.dll
    ...\bin\Release\EFTracingProvider.dll
    ...\bin\Release\EFProviderWrapperToolkit.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference 
...
Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.EnterpriseServices.dll
    ...\bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
  framework assembly path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
  output path: ...\Workflow.UnitTests\FakesAssemblies
  intermediate path: ...\Workflow.UnitTests\obj\Release\Fakes



Fakes: 2 (2 .fakes files)
    Fakes\Workflow.Bll.fakes
    Fakes\Technical.Sdk.fakes
  fakes tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Fakes\fakes.x86.exe
  result: unexpected exception occured (-1002 - 0xfffffc16)
  Fakes assemblies:
    ...\Workflow.UnitTests\FakesAssemblies\Workflow.Bll.Fakes.dll
    ...\Workflow.UnitTests\FakesAssemblies\Workflow.Bll.Fakes.fakesconfig
Done Building Project "...\Workflow.UnitTests\Workflow.UnitTests.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This indicates a problem the Fakes code generator was not prepared to handle gracefully. To troubleshoot it, increase the logging verbosity by setting Verbosity="Noisy" in the Fakes element of the .FAKES files. This will make the Fakes code generator write a lot more information to the MSBuild log and, hopefully, help you identify the problem. Make sure MSBuild log verbosity is set to Detailed or Diagnostic level in Visual Studio options or command line because Fakes does not write diagnostics information to MSBuild log at lower verbosity levels.

If can narrow the problem to a small repro project, I would encourage you to submit it at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio.